# How to change font size and formatting for dropdown lists created in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word template with a 7x16 table and a default font size of 22. This template is used to generate a calendar for 16 weeks via a button click in ms Access. The calendar SHOULD make the month and day 22pt and the contents 7pt. This works for text, but not my dropdown lists (which should be 7pt font and italicized)

I tried using the following code to set the font size of the whole cell to 7pt, but it also set the month and day to 7pt as well:

```vb
'Dim DDown As Word.Contentcontrol and curChar As int earlier in code (for context)
Set cel =  tbl.Cell(i, j)
    Set celRange = cel.Range

    celRange.Characters(curChar).Font.Size = 7 'This shrinks everything to 7pt

    celRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    celRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1

    Set DDown = celRange.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList) 

    'Add items to dropdown
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "Shipping within 7 days"
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On schedule"
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On Hold"


    Set celRange = cel.Range
    celRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    celRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    celRange.Text = vbCrLf  'add a new line between dropdown lists
    celRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd


    celRange.Select
    Set DDown = Nothing
```

The line

> celRange.Characters(curChar).Font.Size = 7

shrinks everything in the cell to 7pt font instead of just the dropdown list. I also would like to italicize the dropdown list. Is it the appearance property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply a font change it's necessary to specify the exact Range to which it should be applied. In theory, that would be:

```
ContentControl.Range.Font.Size = 7
```

The DropDown content control appears to be a special case, however. In my tests, if I apply the font formatting directly to the content control it affects *only* the list of selections and the placeholder text. When an entry is selected, however, the formatting reverts to that of the surrounding text.

Further experimentation revealed that it's also necessary to create a *character style* in the document that contains the desired formatting. This needs to be applied to the content control ***and*** the direct formatting applied, as well.

Here's the code for applying the formatting

```
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "Shipping within 7 days"
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On schedule"
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On Hold"
    DDown.DefaultTextStyle = "Test7"
    DDown.Range.Font.Size = 7
    DDown.Range.Font.Italic = True
```

where "Test7" is the style name I created in the test document.

If the style can't be pre-defined in a document it will need to be created on-the-fly. Here's some sample code for that. The following line should precede the loop (it needs to be executed only once), but follow code that opens/creates the Word document:

```
    CreateFont7Style ActiveDocument, "DdFont7" 'If the code already has a Document object, use that, not ActiveDocument
```

(Remember to substitute the style name specified here for the style name in the line of code, above, that applies the style to the dropdown content controls!)

The code for `CreateFont7Style` (which you can name anything you want, just be sure to change the name in both places):

```
Sub CreateFont7Style(doc As Word.Document, styleName As String)
    Dim st As Word.style
    Dim fontSize As Long
    Dim bItalic As Boolean

    fontSize = 7
    bItalic = True

    Set st = doc.styles.Add(styleName, Word.WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeCharacter)
    st.Font.Size = fontSize
    st.Font.Italic = bItalic
End Sub
```